# ¿Por qué se guarda un registro en blanco en mi base de datos?

Tags: php, java, mysql, android, android-volley

Estoy creando un formulario de registro de usuario en android studio, el cual ya tengo la conexión a la base de datos de manera local, tengo las validaciones de campos vacíos, cuando lleno un registro se me guarda sin problemas en la base de datos, pero me percate de un detalle es que cuando doy clic en el botón registrar aun así estando vacíos todos los campos, en la base de datos se guarda como en blanco, algun método que me haga falta de implemetar.

**conexion.php**

```
<?php

 $host  = "localhost";
 $user = "root";
 $clave = "";
 $database= "logishuman";

 $mysql =  new mysqli($host,$user,$clave,$database);
 $mysql -> set_charset("utf8");

 if ($mysql->connect_error) {
 die("Fallo la conexión" . $mysql->connect_error);
  }else {
  }
  ?>
```

**registroUserFinal.php**

```
  <?php

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    require_once("conexion.php");

    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $nombreUsuario = $_POST["nombreUsuario"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    pass = $_POST["pass"];
    }

   $query = "INSERT INTO t_usuario_final(nombre,nombreUsuario,email,pass) 
   VALUES('$nombre','$nombreUsuario','$email','$pass')";
   $result = $mysql->query($query);

   if ($result === true) {
   echo "Datos intsertados correctamente";
   } else {
   echo "Datos no insertados";
   }
   $mysql->close();
   ?>
```

**RegistroUser.java**

```
public class RegistroUser extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText texnombre, texnombreUsuario, texemail, texpass;
Button btnregistrar;

RequestQueue requestQueue;

private static final String URL ="http://mi ip/LogisHuman/registroUserFinal.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registro_user);

    texnombre =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.texnombre);
    texnombreUsuario =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.texnombreuser);
    texemail =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.texcorreo);
    texpass =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.texpass);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    initUI();

    btnregistrar.setOnClickListener(this);
}
public boolean validarCampos(){
    boolean retorno=true;
     String nombre= texnombre.getText().toString();
     String nombreUsuario= texnombreUsuario.getText().toString();
     String email= texemail.getText().toString();
     String pass= texpass.getText().toString();

    if (nombre.isEmpty()) {
        texnombre.setError("Favor de llenar el campo Nombre");
    }
    if (nombreUsuario.isEmpty()){
        texnombreUsuario.setError("Favor de llenar el campo Nombre de usuario");
        retorno = false;
    }
    if (email.isEmpty()){
        texemail.setError("Favor de llenar el campo Correo electrónico");
        retorno = false;
    }
    if (pass.isEmpty()){
        texpass.setError("Favor de llenar el campo de Contraseña");
        retorno = false;
    }

    return retorno;
}

private void initUI() {
    texnombre = findViewById(R.id.texnombre);
    texnombreUsuario = findViewById(R.id.texnombreuser);
    texemail = findViewById(R.id.texcorreo);
    texpass =  findViewById(R.id.texpass);

    btnregistrar = findViewById(R.id.btnregistrar);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    if (id == R.id.btnregistrar){
    String nombre = texnombre.getText().toString().trim();
    String nombreUsuario = texnombreUsuario.getText().toString().trim();
    String email = texemail.getText().toString().trim();
    String pass = texpass.getText().toString().trim();

    regisUser(nombre, nombreUsuario,email, pass);

    }
}

private void regisUser(String nombre, String nombreUsuario, String email, String pass) {
    StringRequest stringRequest =  new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if (validarCampos()){
                        Toast.makeText(RegistroUser.this, "Registro exitoso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent i = new Intent(RegistroUser.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        RegistroUser.this.startActivity(i);
                        RegistroUser.this.finish();
                    }

                }

            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(RegistroUser.this, "Error al registrar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
    ){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("nombre",nombre);
            params.put("nombreUsuario",nombreUsuario);
            params.put("email",email);
            params.put("pass",pass);
            return params;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
  }
 }
```

**Base de datos Mysql**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta. No dejes datos importantes como ip-usuario-contraseña. Esos datos son personales y tuyos, no te expongas. Otra cosa, estás validando mal, te dejo una respuesta y me confirmas si te sirve.

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo el usuario y la contraseña son los por defecto y la ip era local, no necesita ocultarlos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que llamas al método `validarCampos()` dentro del `onResponse`. Este método se ejecuta una vez que fue recibida la respuesta del servidor. Es decir que en el momento que realizas la validación, el usuario ya fue insertado en la base de datos.

La solución es validar los datos antes de enviarlos al servidor

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    if (id == R.id.btnregistrar) {
        String nombre = texnombre.getText().toString().trim();
        String nombreUsuario = texnombreUsuario.getText().toString().trim();
        String email = texemail.getText().toString().trim();
        String pass = texpass.getText().toString().trim();
        if (validarCampos()) {
            regisUser(nombre, nombreUsuario, email, pass);
        }
    }
}
```

Además en la validación de uno de los campos olvidaste poner la variable en false

```
if (nombre.isEmpty()) {
    texnombre.setError("Favor de llenar el campo Nombre");
    retorno = false; // faltaba esta línea
}
```

Comment: Gracias por el dato de corrección camarada.

Comment: puedes agradecer con un voto positivo

Comment: Y te di un voto de positivo

Answer (score -1):

En tu método de validación corrige lo siguiente:

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(texnombre.getText().toString || texnombre.getText().equals("")){
 texnombre.setError("Tu mensaje");
 texnombre.requestFocus();
 return false;
}
```

Si lo queres hacer como un `String`, debes hacerlo así:

```
String nombre= texnombre.getText().toString();
if(nombre.length() <=0 || nombre.equals("")){
 texnombre.setError("etc");
 // resto de tu código
```

Comment: cheque con tu código pero igual cuando doy clic en el botón de registrar si llenar ninguna campo me guarda nada en la base de datos pero se sigue incrementado.